# SUM on real datatype return incorrect data

Tags: sql-server, database

I have SQL Server and in table I store data in a real datatype column. Next query returns two rows where values have the same meaning:

```
SELECT *
FROM timeseries
WHERE ID = '7' and time BETWEEN '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND '2018-02-01T00:00:00Z' AND
```

2344.54

If I do query with sum function it returns me incorrect value

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) AS sum
FROM timeseries
WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND '2018-02-01T00:00:00Z' AND
      iD = '7'
GROUP BY id
```

the result will be:

4689.07813 Expected 4689.08

I know that this could be related to float-point problem. But how should I resolve this problem?

Comment: `real` is an imprecise data type. If you want precise values, don't use a floating point data type.

Comment: Side note: while it looks neat, [`BETWEEN` on dates and times is generally a bad idea](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: `SUM` promotes `REAL` to `FLOAT` for purposes of calculating (`DECLARE @r REAL = 2344.54; SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(SUM(r), 'BaseType'), SUM(r) FROM (VALUES (@r), (@r)) _(r)`). This compounds any difficulties with rounding, since single-precision numbers promoted to double precision do not have the property that their decimal representations will be identical. Basically, `REAL` should be considered inadequate for any use in aggregates.

Comment: What @JeroenMostert references above is also confirmed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types), so is expected behaviour.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank for your comments, but I didn't get the solution. DB schema defined along ago. I cannot change column type. I there any work around? Maybe some casting?

Comment: Sure, you can cast the field to a `DECIMAL` of desired precision and scale before summing it (e.g. `SUM(CAST(value AS DECIMAL(20, 2)))`). Note that, because this sums rounded results, this can accumulate errors and the final result can be quite a way off from the most accurate result, but that depends entirely on the (intended) precision of the values. Casting the final result might suffice too, depending on whether `FLOAT` summation was precise enough.